# I'm trying to add key listeners to a JPanel in Java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jpanel, keylistener

There's a lot to understand, so stick with me. I have a JPanel inside a JScrollPane, which is inside a JTabbedPane, which is inside a JFrame. Somewhere in that process, I'm losing the ability to add key listeners.

I have this to set up my JFrame

```
public class Cartographer {

    private final JFrame frmMyWorld = new JFrame();
    /**
     * set up our toolbar
     */
    private final JButton addTabb = new JButton("Create New Workspace");
    
    
    //this is where I create the new tabbed pane
    private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private int numberOfTabbs;
    public static boolean isScrolling;
    private static JSlider zoomer;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Cartographer window = new Cartographer();
                    window.frmMyWorld.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Cartographer() { 
        initialize();
        createEvents();
    }
```

I then initialize:

```
private void initialize() {
        
        frmMyWorld.setTitle("My World");
        frmMyWorld.setBounds(0, 0, 1450, 805);
        frmMyWorld.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
        frmMyWorld.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        newTab();
        isScrolling = true;

        //this sets up my slider which I'm using to zoom
        zoomer = new JSlider();
        zoomer.setMinimum(-1000);
        zoomer.setMaximum(1000);
        zoomer.setValue(1000);
        zoomer.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        zoomer.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                if(isScrolling) {
                    hPortion = getHPortion();
                    vPortion = getVPortion();
                }
                isScrolling = false;
                int hScale = (int) getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                int vScale = (int) getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                getSelectedSpace().setZoomFactor(Math.pow(2, (double) zoomer.getValue()/250 - 4));
                getSelectedSpace().setZoomerValue(zoomer.getValue());
                getSelectedSpace().repaint();
                getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue((int) Math.round(hPortion*hScale - (hVisible()/2)));
                getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().setValue((int) Math.round(vPortion*vScale - (vVisible()/2))); 
                getSelectedPane().addNotify();
                getSelectedPane().revalidate();
                getSelectedPane().setDoubleBuffered(true);
                getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().revalidate();
                getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().revalidate();
                getSelectedSpace().repaint();
            }
        });
        
        
        
        
        
        /**and using a group layout, we add a new tab to our JFrame
                 * my original code was using buttons I'm just simplifying the code to make it                  .                */easier to read,that's why I'm using group layour     ,          
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frmMyWorld.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(zoomer, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1335, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(28))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(zoomer, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 624, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 642, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18))
        );
        groupSettingManager(groupLayout);
        
        
        
    }
```

And the newTab() function is what we do when we create a new tab

```
void newTab() {
        //We first create a new workspace with the given dimentions 
        Workspace workSpace = new Workspace(1295*256, 592*256);
//request focus so we can add key listeners
        workSpace.requestFocus();
        //Our workspace sits inside a scroll pane
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(workSpace);
        numberOfTabbs++;
        //our scroll pane sits inside a tabbed pane
        tabbedPane.addTab("Workspace " + numberOfTabbs, scrollPane);
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(numberOfTabbs-1);
        scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                isScrolling = true;
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                isScrolling = true;
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
        
        
    }
```

As you may have noticed, we're requesting focus from the new workspace as soon as it's created, however, that doesn't seem to give it focus

I've tried adding key listeners to the workspace, like so

```
public class Workspace extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
        //we keep every landmass that will appear in the workspace stored in this array
        public ArrayList<Node> protoLandmass = new ArrayList<Node>();
        
        private static Color backGroundColor;
        private int zoomerValue;
        private static double zoomFactor; 
        private static int width;
        private static int height;
        private static boolean zooming = false;

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public Workspace(int w, int h) {
            eventHandlers();
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
            
            backGroundColor = new Color(0,120,255);
            this.setBackground(backGroundColor);
            zoomFactor = 1;
            width = w;
            height = h;
            zoomerValue = 1000;
            this.setFocusable(true);
                        //I've also tried to request focus here, that didn't work either
            //this.requestFocus();
            this.addKeyListener(this);
            //this.requestFocusInWindow();
            repaint();
        }

                ...

                @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            ... 
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            ...
            }   
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            ...
        }
```

The key listeners here don't work, even though I have tried requesting focus in multiple places

The mouse listeners seem to work when I create events here:

```
private void eventHandlers() {
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        ...
                    repaint();
                }
                
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                                ...
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                                ...
                }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                                        ...
                    repaint();
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    ...
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            
            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                        repaint();
                }
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                                       // this one doesn't work either
                        Cartographer.isScrolling = true;
                }
            });
                
                this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

               @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            ...
            
        }
                @override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            ...
            }
                
                
            
        }
                @override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            ... 
        }       
            
    }
```

I tried adding key listeners here, but they didn't work either. I never tried having key listeners in both places at the same time, I'm just showing all the places they have been to make it easier for you.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
  import java.awt.Color;  
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
    import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
    import javax.swing.JSlider;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
    
    
    
    public class Cartographer {
    
        private final JFrame frmMyWorld = new JFrame();
        /**
         * set up our toolbar
         */
        double hPortion = 0;
        double vPortion = 0;
        
        
        //the space that will contain everything that is drawn
        private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
        private int numberOfTabbs;
        public static boolean isScrolling;
        private static JSlider zoomer;
        
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Cartographer window = new Cartographer();
                        window.frmMyWorld.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Create the application.
         */
        public Cartographer() { 
            initialize();
        }
    
        /**
         * Initialise the contents of the frame.
         */
        private void initialize() {
            
            frmMyWorld.setTitle("My World");
            frmMyWorld.setBounds(0, 0, 1450, 805);
            frmMyWorld.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
            frmMyWorld.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
            tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
            newTab();
            isScrolling = true;
    
            /**
             * give everything its position in the window, we're using a group layout
             */
            zoomer = new JSlider();
            zoomer.setMinimum(-1000);
            zoomer.setMaximum(1000);
            zoomer.setValue(1000);
            zoomer.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
            zoomer.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    if(isScrolling) {
                        hPortion = getHPortion();
                        vPortion = getVPortion();
                    }
                    isScrolling = false;
                    int hScale = (int) getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                    int vScale = (int) getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                    getSelectedSpace().setZoomFactor(Math.pow(2, (double) zoomer.getValue()/1000 - 1));
                    getSelectedSpace().setZoomerValue(zoomer.getValue());
                    getSelectedSpace().repaint();
                    getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue((int) Math.round(hPortion*hScale - (hVisible()/2)));
                    getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().setValue((int) Math.round(vPortion*vScale - (vVisible()/2))); 
                    getSelectedPane().addNotify();
                    getSelectedPane().revalidate();
                    getSelectedPane().setDoubleBuffered(true);
                    getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().revalidate();
                    getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().revalidate();
                    getSelectedSpace().repaint();
                }
            });
            
            
            
            
            
            
            GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frmMyWorld.getContentPane());
            groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(zoomer, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1335, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(28))
            );
            groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(zoomer, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 624, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 642, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18))
            );
            groupSettingManager(groupLayout);
            
            
            
        }
        
    
    
        void groupSettingManager(GroupLayout groupLayout) {
                frmMyWorld.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
        }
    
    
        void newTab() {
            //We first create a new workspace with the given dimentions 
            Workspace workSpace = new Workspace(1295*4, 592*4);
            //we need to focus on this new workspace for key listeners to work
            //Our workspace sits inside a scroll pane
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(workSpace);
            numberOfTabbs++;
            //our scroll pane sits inside a tabbed pane
            tabbedPane.addTab("Workspace " + numberOfTabbs, scrollPane);
            workSpace.requestFocus();
            tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(numberOfTabbs-1);
            scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            });
            scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            });
            
            
        }
        
        
        static Workspace getSelectedSpace() {
            return ((Workspace) ((JScrollPane) tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent()).getViewport().getView());
        }
        JScrollPane getSelectedPane() {
            return (JScrollPane) tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
        }
        Workspace getSpace(int i) {
            return ((Workspace) ((JScrollPane) tabbedPane.getComponent(i)).getViewport().getView());
        }
        JScrollPane getPane(int i) {
            return (JScrollPane) tabbedPane.getComponent(i);
        }
        
        
        
         static void setZoomerValue(int i) {
            if(-1000 <= i && i <= 1000)
                zoomer.setValue(i);
        }
        int getZoomerValue() {
            return zoomer.getValue();   
        }
        
        public double getHPortion() {
            int m = getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum();
            int v = getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue();
            double a = getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount()/2;
            return (v + a)/m;
        }
        public double getVPortion() {
            int m = getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
            int v = getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
            double a = getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount()/2;
            return (v +a)/m;
        }
        public int hVisible() {
            return getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount();
        }
        public int vVisible() {
            return getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount();
        }
    
    
    }

    import java.awt.Color; 
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Workspace extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
        //we keep every landmass that will appear in the workspace stored in this array
        
        private static Color backGroundColor;
        private static Color foreGroundColor;
        private int zoomerValue;
        private static double zoomFactor; 
        private static int width;
        private static int height;

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public Workspace(int w, int h) {
            eventHandlers();
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
            
            backGroundColor = Color.BLACK;
            foreGroundColor = Color.WHITE;
            this.setBackground(backGroundColor);
            zoomFactor = 1;
            width = w;
            height = h;
            zoomerValue = 1000;
            this.setFocusable(true);
            this.requestFocus();
            this.addKeyListener(this);
            //this.requestFocusInWindow();
            repaint();
        }
        




        public Workspace(LayoutManager layout) {
            super(layout);
            
        }

        public Workspace(boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
            super(isDoubleBuffered);
            
        }

        public Workspace(LayoutManager layout, boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
            super(layout, isDoubleBuffered);
            
        }
        
        public double getZoomFactor() {
            return zoomFactor;
        }
        public void setZoomFactor(double z) {
            zoomFactor = z;
            repaint();
        }
        public void adjustZoomFactor(int z) {
            zoomFactor = Math.pow(2, z);
            repaint();
        }
        
        
        public int getZoomerValue() {
            return zoomerValue;
        }
        public void setZoomerValue(int i) {
            zoomerValue = i;
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        /**
         * Paint Function and supplement functions 
         */
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;
            zoom(g2);
            //a for loop to run the same function on each of the landmasses to draw them all    
            for(int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
                for(int j = Math.floorMod(i, 2); j < 16; j+=2) {
                    g2.setColor(foreGroundColor);
                    g2.fillRect(148*i, 148*j, 148, 148);
                    g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g2.drawString("(" + i + "," + j + ")",148*i+66,148*j+72);
                }
            this.setBackground(backGroundColor);
            
        }
        private void zoom(Graphics2D g) {
            //if(zooming) g.translate(-getMousePosition().x, -getMousePosition().y);
            g.scale(zoomFactor,zoomFactor);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) Math.round(width*zoomFactor), (int) Math.round(height*zoomFactor)));
            this.validate();
            //if(zooming) g.translate(getMousePosition().x, getMousePosition().y);

        }
        
        
        
        /**
         * Any events that occur within the workspace happen here
         */
        private void eventHandlers() {
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    foreGroundColor = Color.BLUE;
                    repaint();
                }
                
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    backGroundColor = Color.GRAY;
                    repaint();
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    foreGroundColor = Color.WHITE;
                    repaint();
                }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    backGroundColor = Color.BLACK;
                    repaint();
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    Cartographer.setZoomerValue(zoomerValue);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            
            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                        repaint();
                }
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                        Cartographer.isScrolling = true;
                }
            });
            
            this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    foreGroundColor = Color.RED;
                }
            });
            
            
        }
        
        
        public int mousePositionX() {
            return (int) Math.round(getMousePosition().x/zoomFactor);
        }
        public int mousePositionY() {
            return (int) Math.round(getMousePosition().y/zoomFactor);
        }


        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case 38 : if(zoomerValue < 1000) { zoomerValue+=5; Cartographer.setZoomerValue(zoomerValue);} 
                repaint();
            break;
            case 40 : if(zoomerValue > -1000) {zoomerValue-=5; Cartographer.setZoomerValue(zoomerValue);} 
                System.out.println(zoomerValue);
                repaint();
            break;
            default: repaint();
            }
                
                
            
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                
        }
        
        
        

}
```

Comment: If you've done any searching on this, especially on this site, you'll see that most will recommend that you *shouldn't* use KeyListeners for something like this. Try key bindings instead, as it won't give you all the same focus requirement issues that KeyListeners do. Also, for better answers, best to create and post a valid [mre] with your question. Please read the link to see what this is and how it can help you and us.

Comment: I've taken away a lot from my code, but because I'm placing a Jpanel inside a JScrollPane inside a JTabbedPane inside a JFrame, I feel like adding all of those things are necessary. I also want to add that my mouseListeners work for some reason to see if that had anything to do with it.

Comment: Only you can decide what is necessary or not, but I am saying that no one here can compile or run your or test your code. ***Again***, please look at the [mre] link to see why you really should be posting one of these in your question and not the snippets of unrunnable code that you're currently posting. Note also that this is not a request for the entire program, but likely you'll want to create a new small program that runs and that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you get a decent answer soon without creating an MRE, then feel free to ignore my suggestion. But myself, given what I see, I again can only give broad recommendations that you try [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (tutorial link) to see if that would work. Another unrelated issue: you look to be over-using the `static` modifier, and this can come back to bite you.

Comment: So you mean, produce code that can be tested? Where would submit that code?

Comment: Where? Here of course, as code-formatted text. Please read the link, as I've mentioned several times; it will explain much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, using your code, I can demonstrate that Key Bindings does in fact work inside of a nested component, here the bindings are on the g-key, for "green". When the key is pressed, the foreground color of the component changes to green.

The bindings:

```
private void eventHandlers() {
    
    // .......

    // add some key bindings to test that they work
    InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

    // when the g-key is pressed, the foreground color is set to green
    KeyStroke gDownKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_G, 0, false);
    KeyStroke gUpKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_G, 0, true);

    inputMap.put(gDownKey, "gDown");
    actionMap.put("gDown", new ForeGroundColorAction(Color.GREEN));

    inputMap.put(gUpKey, "gUp");
    actionMap.put("gUp", new ForeGroundColorAction(Color.WHITE));
}

private class ForeGroundColorAction extends AbstractAction {
    private Color color;

    public ForeGroundColorAction(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        foreGroundColor = color;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

And my MRE demonstration program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Cartographer {
    private final JFrame frmMyWorld = new JFrame();
    double hPortion = 0;
    double vPortion = 0;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private int numberOfTabbs;
    public boolean isScrolling;
    private JSlider zoomer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Cartographer window = new Cartographer();
                    window.frmMyWorld.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Cartographer() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmMyWorld.setTitle("My World");
        frmMyWorld.setBounds(0, 0, 1450, 805);
        frmMyWorld.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 100));
        frmMyWorld.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        newTab();
        isScrolling = true;
        zoomer = new JSlider();
        zoomer.setMinimum(-1000);
        zoomer.setMaximum(1000);
        zoomer.setValue(1000);
        zoomer.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        zoomer.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                if (isScrolling) {
                    hPortion = getHPortion();
                    vPortion = getVPortion();
                }
                isScrolling = false;
                int hScale = (int) getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                int vScale = (int) getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                getSelectedSpace().setZoomFactor(Math.pow(2, (double) zoomer.getValue() / 1000 - 1));
                getSelectedSpace().setZoomerValue(zoomer.getValue());
                getSelectedSpace().repaint();
                getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar()
                        .setValue((int) Math.round(hPortion * hScale - (hVisible() / 2)));
                getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar()
                        .setValue((int) Math.round(vPortion * vScale - (vVisible() / 2)));
                getSelectedPane().addNotify();
                getSelectedPane().revalidate();
                getSelectedPane().setDoubleBuffered(true);
                getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().revalidate();
                getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().revalidate();
                getSelectedSpace().repaint();
            }
        });
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frmMyWorld.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(zoomer, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1335,
                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(28)));
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(zoomer, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 624,
                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 642,
                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(18)));
        groupSettingManager(groupLayout);
    }

    void groupSettingManager(GroupLayout groupLayout) {
        frmMyWorld.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }

    void newTab() {
        // We first create a new workspace with the given dimentions
        Workspace workSpace = new Workspace(1295 * 4, 592 * 4, this);
        // we need to focus on this new workspace for key listeners to work
        // Our workspace sits inside a scroll pane
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(workSpace);
        numberOfTabbs++;
        // our scroll pane sits inside a tabbed pane
        tabbedPane.addTab("Workspace " + numberOfTabbs, scrollPane);
        workSpace.requestFocus();
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(numberOfTabbs - 1);
        scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                isScrolling = true;
            }

        });
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                isScrolling = true;
            }
        });
    }

    Workspace getSelectedSpace() {
        return ((Workspace) ((JScrollPane) tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent()).getViewport().getView());
    }

    JScrollPane getSelectedPane() {
        return (JScrollPane) tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
    }

    Workspace getSpace(int i) {
        return ((Workspace) ((JScrollPane) tabbedPane.getComponent(i)).getViewport().getView());
    }

    JScrollPane getPane(int i) {
        return (JScrollPane) tabbedPane.getComponent(i);
    }

    void setZoomerValue(int i) {
        if (-1000 <= i && i <= 1000)
            zoomer.setValue(i);
    }

    int getZoomerValue() {
        return zoomer.getValue();
    }

    public double getHPortion() {
        int m = getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum();
        int v = getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue();
        double a = getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount() / 2;
        return (v + a) / m;
    }

    public double getVPortion() {
        int m = getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
        int v = getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
        double a = getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount() / 2;
        return (v + a) / m;
    }

    public int hVisible() {
        return getSelectedPane().getHorizontalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount();
    }

    public int vVisible() {
        return getSelectedPane().getVerticalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount();
    }
}

class Workspace extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    // we keep every landmass that will appear in the workspace stored in this array
    private Color backGroundColor;
    private Color foreGroundColor;
    private int zoomerValue;
    private Cartographer cartographer;
    private double zoomFactor;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Workspace(int w, int h, Cartographer cartographer) {
        this.cartographer = cartographer;
        eventHandlers();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        backGroundColor = Color.BLACK;
        foreGroundColor = Color.WHITE;
        this.setBackground(backGroundColor);
        zoomFactor = 1;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        zoomerValue = 1000;
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocus();
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        setBackground(backGroundColor); // !!s
    }

    public Workspace(LayoutManager layout) {
        super(layout);
    }

    public Workspace(boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
        super(isDoubleBuffered);
    }

    public Workspace(LayoutManager layout, boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
        super(layout, isDoubleBuffered);
    }

    public double getZoomFactor() {
        return zoomFactor;
    }

    public void setZoomFactor(double z) {
        zoomFactor = z;
        repaint();
    }

    public void adjustZoomFactor(int z) {
        zoomFactor = Math.pow(2, z);
        repaint();
    }

    public int getZoomerValue() {
        return zoomerValue;
    }

    public void setZoomerValue(int i) {
        zoomerValue = i;
    }

    @Override // must override paintComponent, not paint
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // never forget this!

        // best to only scale a copy of the Graphics object so as not to break the painting chain
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        zoom(g2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
            for (int j = Math.floorMod(i, 2); j < 16; j += 2) {
                g2.setColor(foreGroundColor);
                g2.fillRect(148 * i, 148 * j, 148, 148);
                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2.drawString("(" + i + "," + j + ")", 148 * i + 66, 148 * j + 72);
            }
        }
        g2.dispose();  // dispose of copy

        // this.setBackground(backGroundColor); // !! does not belong in painting method
    }

    private void zoom(Graphics2D g) {
        // if(zooming) g.translate(-getMousePosition().x, -getMousePosition().y);
        g.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        this.setPreferredSize(
                new Dimension((int) Math.round(width * zoomFactor), (int) Math.round(height * zoomFactor)));
        this.validate();
        // if(zooming) g.translate(getMousePosition().x, getMousePosition().y);
    }

    /**
     * Any events that occur within the workspace happen here
     */
    private void eventHandlers() {
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                foreGroundColor = Color.BLUE;
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                backGroundColor = Color.GRAY;
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                foreGroundColor = Color.WHITE;
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                backGroundColor = Color.BLACK;
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                cartographer.setZoomerValue(zoomerValue);
                repaint();
            }
        });
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                cartographer.isScrolling = true;
            }
        });
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                foreGroundColor = Color.RED;
            }
        });

        // add some key bindings to test that they work
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        // when the g-key is pressed, the foreground color is set to green
        KeyStroke gDownKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_G, 0, false);
        KeyStroke gUpKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_G, 0, true);

        inputMap.put(gDownKey, "gDown");
        actionMap.put("gDown", new ForeGroundColorAction(Color.GREEN));

        inputMap.put(gUpKey, "gUp");
        actionMap.put("gUp", new ForeGroundColorAction(Color.WHITE));
    }

    private class ForeGroundColorAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Color color;

        public ForeGroundColorAction(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            foreGroundColor = color;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public int mousePositionX() {
        return (int) Math.round(getMousePosition().x / zoomFactor);
    }

    public int mousePositionY() {
        return (int) Math.round(getMousePosition().y / zoomFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case 38:
                if (zoomerValue < 1000) {
                    zoomerValue += 5;
                    cartographer.setZoomerValue(zoomerValue);
                }
                repaint();
                break;
            case 40:
                if (zoomerValue > -1000) {
                    zoomerValue -= 5;
                    cartographer.setZoomerValue(zoomerValue);
                }
                System.out.println(zoomerValue);
                repaint();
                break;
            default:
                repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Note my removal of many static modifiers. Also, you shouldn't draw in paint but in paintComponent and don't forget to call the super's method for housekeeping painting. Also, scaling should usually be done on a copy of the Graphics object given by the JVM.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at the paintComponent changes you've made, I'll have a look at the rest in the morning. Also, do you mind explaining what the super.paintComponent actually does and why using paintComponent is better than Paint?